# Constraint layout centering

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a view that should look as follows

[image]

When the blue view is gone, i want the red view to be centered relative to its parent

However, the content of the blue view needs to be centered relative to its parent all the time.

In theory i should make the constraint end of the blue view to be the parent, but i need the red view to be there, and push the blue view to the left with its width.

If i make the blueview end constraint to be the start of the red view, i get the content centered according to the blueview, instead of according to the white view.

How do I achieve what I need ?

Comment: `the content of the blue view needs to be centered relative to its parent all the time.` please elaborate more (Is its parent is the blue or white view?

Comment: I want the content of the blue view be centered to the white view

Answer (score 2):

From the title of your question I assume you want to achieve this using `ConstraintLayout`. In that case, it would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_blue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_red"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_red"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v_blue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's a simplified layout, but it should correspond to your case.

Comment: how is the content of the blue view will be centered relative to the parent ?

Comment: I read your comment to your question, I think I finally understand what you want. Just to be clear, the parent of contents of BLUE view is the BLUE view, but I guess you meant the WHITE view, your question is unclear. My answer, the content of the BLUE view cannot be centered relative to the WHITE view, because they don't know about the WHITE view. That being said, as `ConstraintLayout` is used, you can flatten your layout in order to center what you need, i.e. remove BLUE view and constraint its original content to the WHITE view.

Comment: I can't give you any specific example, if you want help with flattening the layout, please update your question with actual layout code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and in theory, when a view is gone, `constraintlayout` auto adjects the views in the hierarchy, the only thing you need to concern about is to stretch the visible view to match the size of the container in this case, for content in the layout, you can use linear layout and make their gravity center, in this way they will stay in the center even after stretched or centered
for changing the layout parameters code is given below, I hope it works.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
layoutParams = getLayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height, top);

TextView textView;
textView = new TextView(_registerNewMealActivity);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: my problem is not when the view is gone, and i dont want to create views in code